# Using Apple's Network Framework, is there a way to do connectionless UDP?

Tags: ios, macos, network-framework

I'm trying to establish a peer to peer datagram exchange. Ya, I'm doing hole punching and using a remote stun server. Unfortunately, I'm finding that I have to use GCDAsycnUdpSocket, which, while a fine library, isn't quite as convenient as Network. However, it seems you have to create a bound connection with Network framework in order to send, which later results in ICMP rejection. For now, it seems I need to use GCDAsycnUdpSocket, where I can do connectionless sending. However, I thought I'd reach out to see if I overlooked something in the Network framework which would let me send/receive without creating a bound connection. As an aside, I did try setting the includePeerToPeer to true in the connection creation, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: UDP is a connectionless transport, but the network framework uses a connection based abstraction on top of the UDP layer. If you don't want that connection paradigm, don't use the Network framework.  I haven't captured packets from the network framework but I would surprised if it operated any differently "on the wire". The connection with UDP transport is purely logical, providing a mapping to route incoming datagrams to the appropriate NWConnection based on source/destination socket pairs.  If your far end doesn't use a consistent UDP source socket then you can't use the network framework

Comment: I don't think its purely logical, I think there's a bind being performed, which results in incoming packets being rejected (ICMP not reachable) if the UDP packet indicates its from a different IP than the connected IP, at least that's been what I've observed.

Comment: There is no concept of a bind in UDP at the network level. It is connectionless. The Network framework does implement a connection oriented abstraction on top.  If one side of your connection doesn't have a clear "client" role and the other a clear "server" role you can't use Network Framework since it needs known send/receive socket pairs for data gram delivery at the session layer.

Comment: If a UDP arrives from a different IP then it will be treated as a new connection by the network framework; it must be delivered to a socket that has an `NWListener` associated with it.  It can't be delivered as a "reply" to the high port that was used by a previous send.

Comment: Thanks, I think that clarifies things quite a bit and tells me that I need to not use Network Framework for peer to peer data exchanges.